# Spring Security: web security ignored url gets handled by a filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have spring security configuration which looks somehow like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().regexMatchers(POST, "a regex pattern here");
}
```

It worked properly, means it allowed unauthenticated POST request to URLs matching the pattern.

Then I introduced a filter and added it in the next way.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .addFilterAfter(
                      myFilter, 
                      AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class
                )
                ...
}
```

**Problem:** Requests to the ignored url are still handled by the newly introduced filter.

The `myFilter` is an instance of a class extending `OncePerRequestFilter`.

**Question:** How to make filter ignore requests that declared to be ignored in `WebSecurity`?